# How can I delete values from corresponding lists?

Tags: python

I have a data set that I am using to plot a scatter plot, I have sorted this data into two separate lists, "time" and "height". Each index in the "time" list corresponds to the same index in the "height" list. The problem is that occasionally the instruments used to measure the data malfunctioned so that some of the height values read as zero. So I need to delete every index in both the time and height lists where the height reads as zero.
Here is the section of code that I'm using:

```
    for i in range(0, np.size(time)):
        if height[i]=0
            del time[i]
            del height[i]
```

The idea behind this was that all the values of the height list would be searched for the values equal to zero and then they would be deleted, and the corresponding indices in the time list would also be deleted, and everything would be cool beans.
However, I get this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "NewData.py", line 38, in <module>
        if height[i]=0:
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can anyone explain how to fix this, or just how to write a new code to achieve the same thing?

Comment: Do _not_ do this.

Comment: You should be doing `if height[i] == 0:` right now you're trying to assign height[i] to 0.

Answer (score 3):

You must *not* modify the list as you iterate over it. This produces side effects, as the loop is not aware of the deletion occurring.

Here's a better way, using a list comprehension:

```
time = [x for i, x in enumerate(time) if height[i]]
height = [x for x in height if x]
```

This creates a new list using a list comprehension by keeping only the elements you wish not to remove.

Comment: Technically he could modify the list while iterating over the indexes provided he iterated from the highest index to the lowest.  Of course it's still a bad idea because it's incredibly inefficient (all those left-shifts whenever an item is deleted).

Comment: @StevenRumbalski True, I'll agree it's possible.

Comment: No, it would make absolutely no sense for huge amounts of data because of the bad algorithm.  Removing item 0 in a million item array involves copying 999,999,999 items one item to the left.  I was just pointing out that "must not" is really a "should not".

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Are you talking about lists or numpy arrays? Sorry, got confused.

Comment: Lists, as OP is using `del` to remove items, which you can't do to a numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use `np.delete()` in `while` loop like that:

```
i=0
limit=np.size(time)
while(i<limit):
    if height[i]==0:
        time=np.delete(time,i)
        height=np.delete(height,i)
        limit-=1
    else:
        i+=1
```

Note that if the height is 0, the counter doesn't increment, with that you ensure to not indexing over the new array dimension.

Answer (score 0):

As with most languages, deleting things from a list while you are iterating over it is not a great idea.  The reason being is that the end point for `i` is not checked each time through the loop.  If, for instance, `np.size(time)==10`, then after the first deleted element, the new length of `time` would be `9`, but `i` would still keep incrementing to `9`, leading you to attempt to access element `time[9]`, which doesn't exist anymore.

Fortunately, Python has many ways to deal with this that won't significantly impact performance over the sample you have listed.  You can iterate backwards:

```
for i in reversed(range(len(time))):
    if height[i] == 0:
        del time[i]
        del height[i]
```

This works because deleting element `i` does not affect elements `0:i-1`.  You probably shouldn't do this, though, because it's terribly inefficient (especially for large lists).

You can also build a list of elements to keep using list comprehensions:

```
keep = [i for i,h in enumerate(height) if h != 0]
time = [time[i] for i in keep]
height = [height[i] for i in keep]
```

This might be the more "Pythonic" way of doing this, for whatever that's worth.

Given you are already using numpy, you might want to use numpy to select the appropriate elements for you:

```
import numpy as np

time = np.array(time)
height = np.array(height)

time = time[height != 0]
height = height[height != 0]
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not just ignore the ones where height is zero.  Involves no deletion, creating a new list or copying elements.  So as you're plotting the scatter plot, only update the plot when the height is greater than zero.

Comment: This isn't right, because it makes assumptions on OP's use case.

Comment: You should add evidence that support what you are saying