# Conditionally delete elements from a list

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have a list of days in a year:

```
days = [0,1,2,3,...,363,364,365]
```

And a list of minutes of cloud on that day that is the same length:

```
weather = [0,60,150,80,...,120,90,150]
```

I want to delete the items in `days` if the corresponding index value of `weather` is greater than some condition, e.g if

```
condition = 120
```

Then my `days` list would look like:

```
days_new = [0,1,3,...,364]
```

So I'm thinking of something like:

```
for i in xrange(len(days)):
    if weather[i] > condition:
        del days[i]
```

Is there a 'neater' way of doing these kind of operations?

edit: my `days` list won't necessarily correspond to their indexes, this is a simplified case

Comment: simply for history, i wouldn't delete from the old list, i would creqate a new list and add items that meet the condition to it and omit ones that do not. Other than that, this idea looks solid

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I delete values from corresponding lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45019685/how-can-i-delete-values-from-corresponding-lists)

Comment: You've said in your question that you want to delete items if the index value is greater than some condition, but in the example you have removed the index `363` where `weather[363] == condition`, presenting 'greater than *or equal to*' logic. Which one do you require?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the days don't match their `index`, you can still use `list-comprehension` and use `enumerate` to get the `indices` as the following:

```
days = [x for i, x in enumerate(days) if weather[i] <= condition]
```

Comment: Why not use `zip()` instead?

Comment: @Szabolcs just incase the `lists` don't have the same length

Comment: Well `zip` is safe for that scenario, while your `enumerate` approach will cause `IndexError: list index out  of range` if the length of the `days` list is bigger than the length of `weather`.

Comment: This answer gives a logic error in the case where `weather[i] == condition`. OP said he wants to delete from the list if the value is greater than, not include in the list if the value is less than. A `<=` should be used instead of `<`.

Answer (score 0):

I would not suggest to mutate the state of the old list, create a new one rather:

```
>>> threshold = 60
>>> days = [0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> weather = [0, 60, 150, 80]
>>> [d for d, w in zip(days, weather) if w > threshold]
```

It will output:

```
[2, 3]
```